Azure - Assign Network Contributor in PIM
I want to via powershell to make an Azure role (Network Contributor) eligible in PIM under a specific scope (tenant root group actually).
I can assign normal entra roles (global admin) as eligible using:
New-MgRoleManagementDirectoryRoleEligibilityScheduleRequest
But what is the equivalent for azure roles?
I have tried New-MgRoleManagementDirectoryRoleEligibilityScheduleRequest and New-AzRoleAssignment (but could not get it to work)

Do you want to add eligible role or active role of  Network Contributor to a user?

It's actually a group that I want add.. So all users in that group will be eligible to take network contributor role on the tenant root level scope

New-MgRoleManagementUnifiedRoleEligibilityScheduleRequest   -PrincipalId "<user or group object ID>"
-RoleDefinitionId "b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c"   -DirectoryScopeId "/"
-Action "AdminAssign"   -Duration "10:00:00"
-Justification "Eligible assignment for Network Contributor role" `
-ScheduleInfo @{StartDateTime="2022-01-01T00:00:00Z"; EndDateTime="2022-01-01T10:00:00Z"} try this

Related MS Docs- Tutorial: Assign Microsoft Entra roles in Privileged Identity Management using Microsoft Graph PowerShell

Assign administrative roles by using PIM for Microsoft Entra roles APIs


@GojiraAzure Is this below solution works for you?

Hi Arko.. I can not find any information on New-MgRoleManagementUnifiedRoleEligibilityScheduleRequest
Not when I google it or in the link you provided.. It sounds exactly like what I need.. should that cmdlet not be mentioned in the link? (even though the links says entra role and this is an azure role)

Initially, I created Security group TestPIMRole and added two members to it:

To assign  an eligible role assignment of Network Contributor use below powershell script:
$guid = "<guid>"
$startTime = Get-Date -Format o 
$scope = "/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/"
New-AzRoleEligibilityScheduleRequest -Name $guid -Scope $scope -ExpirationDuration P365D -ExpirationType AfterDuration -PrincipalId <Object_id of Group> -RequestType AdminAssign -RoleDefinitionId /subscriptions/<subscription id>/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/4d97b98b-1d4f-4787-a291-c67834d212e7 -ScheduleInfoStartDateTime $startTime

Output:


References:
New-AzRoleEligibilityScheduleRequest (Az.Resources) 
